# Mongoose, creating a new model

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I had model Product, he was added without problem to db "products"

```
router.post('/create', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  var newProduct = {
    title: req.body.name,
    price: req.body.price,
    description: req.body.description,
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
   // category: req.body.category
  }
  var product = new Product(newProduct);
  product.save(function (err, product) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(404).json({
        message: 'Can not create this product'
      })
    } else {
      console.log('added');
      res.send(product);
    }
  });
});
```

Now i have model Category i was created http.post and  all is working, but I have no idea where this things sended by post are save in database mongo

```
router.post('/create', function (req, res, next) {
  var newCategory = {
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description
  }
  var category = new Category(newCategory);

  category.save(function (err, category) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(404).json({
        message: 'Can not create this category'
      })
    } else {
      console.log('added');
      res.send(category);
    }
  });
});
```

Can someone exaplain me??

Comment: it should be 'categories', but you'd better show your model file.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/28eb1f9a74b4b7692d194c49c49c35f9
Working but why 'categories' ??

Comment: mongoose automatically transforms your model name to plurual form

Answer (score 0):

As far as mongoose automatically transforms your model name to plurual forms, it should be - **categories**.

**Update:**
If you still want your singular naming, you can try something like this:

```
const Category = mongoose.model('Category ', Category Schema, 'Category ');
```